# Creating a defmatch in maxima

Tags: maxima

Inspired by the [documentation](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_34.html#Item_003a-Introduction-to-Rules-and-Patterns), in particular the part that shows how to write a function that will check if an expression is a definite integral, I'm trying to write some code that will recognise whether an expression is an infinite sum.

```
matchdeclare(x, atom);
matchdeclare(n, atom);
simp: false;
defmatch (checkinfsum, 'sum (f, n, 1, inf));
'sum(cos(n*x)/n^2,n,1,inf);
```

returns `false` and I cannot quite figure out why. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You are missign `matchdeclare(f, all)`.

```
matchdeclare(n, atom)$
matchdeclare(f, all)$
defmatch(checkinfsum, 'sum (f, n, 1, inf)), simp = false$
e: 'sum(cos(n*x)/n^2,n,1,inf)$
checkinfsum(e);
```

returns

```
                                         cos(n x)
(%o5)                        [n = n, f = --------]
                                             2
                                            n
```